# Memory addresses

Tags: c, debugging, gdb, buffer-overflow

I am workin on Overthewire narnia2(ctf game).
Currently I am learning how to use the gdb and I have a simple question.

```
    (gdb) x/200x $esp-0xac
0xffffd5a4: 0x08048534  0xffffd5c8  0xf7e5b7d0  0xffffd5c8
0xffffd5b4: 0xf7ffd920  0xf7e5b7d5  0x08048494  0x08048534
0xffffd5c4: 0xffffd5c8  0x6850c031  0x68732f2f  0x69622f68
0xffffd5d4: 0x50e3896e  0x89e18953  0xcd0bb0c2  0x41414180
0xffffd5e4: 0x41414141  0x41414141  0x41414141  0x41414141
0xffffd5f4: 0x41414141  0x41414141  0x41414141  0x41414141
0xffffd604: 0x41414141  0x41414141  0x41414141  0x41414141
0xffffd614: 0x41414141  0x41414141  0x41414141  0x41414141
0xffffd624: 0x41414141  0x41414141  0x41414141  0x41414141
0xffffd634: 0x41414141  0x41414141  0x41414141  0x41414141
0xffffd644: 0x41414141  0x62626262  0xf7e2a200  0x00000002
0xffffd654: 0xffffd6e4  0xffffd6f0  0x00000000  0x00000000
0xffffd664: 0x00000000  0xf7fc5000  0xf7ffdc0c  0xf7ffd000
0xffffd674: 0x00000000  0x00000002  0xf7fc5000  0x00000000
0xffffd684: 0x59e07c0a  0x6308501a  0x00000000  0x00000000



    (gdb) x/200x $esp

0xffffd7a0: 0x000036b2  0x0000000e  0x000036b2  0x00000017
0xffffd7b0: 0x00000001  0x00000019  0xffffd7eb  0x0000001a
0xffffd7c0: 0x00000000  0x0000001f  0xffffdfe8  0x0000000f
0xffffd7d0: 0xffffd7fb  0x00000000  0x00000000  0x00000000
0xffffd7e0: 0x00000000  0x00000000  0x8b000000  0xb1cfbc04
0xffffd7f0: 0x91563e77  0xcb1ff506  0x6957e20c  0x00363836
0xffffd800: 0x00000000  0x00000000  0x00000000  0x72616e2f
0xffffd810: 0x2f61696e  0x6e72616e  0x00326169  0x41414141
0xffffd820: 0x41414141  0x41414141  0x41414141  0x41414141
0xffffd830: 0x41414141  0x41414141  0x41414141  0x41414141
0xffffd840: 0x41414141  0x41414141  0x41414141  0x41414141
0xffffd850: 0x41414141  0x41414141  0x41414141  0x41414141
0xffffd860: 0x41414141  0x41414141  0x41414141  0x41414141
0xffffd870: 0x41414141  0x41414141  0x41414141  0x41414141
0xffffd880: 0x41414141  0x31414141  0x2f6850c0  0x6868732f
0xffffd890: 0x6e69622f  0x5350e389  0xc289e189  0x80cd0bb0
```

what am I looking at when I do $esp-0xac? I've also seen other methods like $esp-0x14, but why not do plain $esp?
what is the most used and why?

Answer (score 1):

> what am i looking at when i do $esp-0xac?

The `$esp` register points to the boundary (in memory) between used and unused portion of the stack. On `i*86` processors, stack grows to lower addresses, so anything above (at higher addresses) `$esp` contains used portion of the stack (local variables, return addresses, saved registers, etc.) and anything below (at lower addresses) contains *currently* unused portion of the stack.

The command `x/200x $esp-0xac` then examines contents of 43 32-bit words of currently used stack, and 157 words of unused portion of the stack.

> ive also seen other methods like $esp-0x14, but why not do plain $esp?

The `$esp-0x14` would let you look at the last 5 used words of the stack. Using `$esp` would let you look at the unused portion of the stack. You *could* do that, but it's somewhat pointless.

> what is the most used and why?

Examining stack is useful when you want to where some specific value is stored (e.g. during exploit / stack buffer overflow analysis), or when you are debugging at the machine instruction level.

Comment: Very helpful. Thank you very much for giving me this clarity.